# Factor $(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4$

Tags: factoring

Title says it all, I just want to know how to factor $(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4$. I only know that it's possible to factor, but got no idea how to do it. If it were a single-variable polynomial I could try to find rational roots or something, but I'm lost with this one.

Comment: $2x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4^xy^3 + 2y^4$ can be split up as $(2x^4 + 2x^3y + 2x^2y^2) + (2x^3y + 2x^2y^2 + 2xy^3) + (2x^2y^2 + 2xy^3 + 2y^4)$, or $2(x^2 + xy + y^2)^2$.

Comment: Final answer : $$x^4+y^4+(x+y)^4=2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond what I have posted, it cannot be factored in the real field. If you want to factor it in the complex field, you have to learn how to solve a quartic equation because you essentially need to know that roots of $(t+1)^4 + t^4 + 1 = 2t^4 + 4t^3 + 6t^2 + 4t + 2 = 0$, it can be simplified to $t^4 + 2t^3 + 3t^2 + 2t + 1 = 0$.Lucky enough, this is equal to $(t^2 + t + 1)^2$

Thus $x^4 + y^4 + (x + y)^4 = 2(x^2 + xy + y^2)^2$.
No further factorization is available in the real field...

Best wishes

Comment: Are you sure about the last line? The coefficient of $x^4$ on the LHS is 2, but the coefficient of $x^4$ on the RHS is 1. Moreover, plugging in $x=1$, $y=0$, we get that LHS = 2, but RHS = 1. What I'm trying to say is, there is clearly something wrong with your last line... [Figured it out - **you are missing a '2' in front of the brackets on the RHS of the last equality** - I am not being allowed to edit your answer for some reason]

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$(x+y)^4 + x^4 + y^4 = y^4 ((x/y+1)^4 + (x/y)^4 + 1)$$
and see if you can factor $((t+1)^4 + t^4 + 1$.  There is a quadratic factor.

Comment: Just a quick question, did you do this manipulation just so you can have it in one variable? When factoring, is it always best to try to reduce it to one variable?

Comment: This answer seems the most informative and straightforward for the OP - it gives a good general method for factoring polynomials in two variables by reducing it to something in one variable.

Comment: This works when a two-variable polynomial is homogeneous.  In general, things are more complicated.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah yes, I didn't mean to be quite so general, but yes, it is a nice reliable method of factoring homogeneous two variable polynomials, which is accessible to those who have not come across many polynomials in more than one variable before.

Answer (score 3):

This is a symmetric polynomial in $x$ and $y$, hence it can be expressed, by *Newton's theorem*, as a polynomial in $s=x+y$ and $p=xy$.

Indeed $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=s^2-2p$, whence
$$x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=(s^2-2p)^2-2p^2=s^4-4ps^2+2p^2.$$
Therefore
$$(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4=2s^4-4ps^2+2p^2=2(s^2-p)^2=2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2.$$

$x^2+xy+y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbf R[x]$, but  factors in  $\mathbf C[x]$ as
$$(x-jy)(x-j^2y)\quad\text{where } j\; \text{and }j^2 \;\text{are the non-real cubic roots of unity.}$$

Answer (score 1):

I know that using complex algebra, we can factor $x^4 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2 + \sqrt{2}xy)(x^2 + y^2 - \sqrt{2}xy)$. I have no idea how to proceed forward...
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, there is a slight mistake, I forgot factoring 2. Thus $x^4 + y^4 + (x+y)^4 = 2(x^2 + xy + y^2)^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2+2xy)^2+(x^2+y^2)^2-2(xy)^2=\\
[(x^2+y^2+2xy)^2-(xy)^2]+[(x^2+y^2)^2-(xy)^2]=\\
(x^2+y^2+xy)(x^2+y^2+3xy)+(x^2+y^2+xy)(x^2+y^2-xy)=\\
(x^2+y^2+xy)(2x^2+2y^2+2xy)=2(x^2+y^2+xy)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4 + y^4 + (x + y)^4
=2 x^4 + 4 x^3 y + 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 x y^3 + 2 y^4$$
$$=x (x (x (2 x + 4 y) + 6 y^2) + 4 y^3) + 2 y^4
=2 x^4 + y (4 x^3 + y (6 x^2 + y (4 x + 2 y)))$$
$$=4 y^2 (x^2 + x y) + 2 (x^2 + x y)^2 + 2 y^4
=2 (x^4 + 2 x^3 y + 3 x^2 y^2 + 2 x y^3 + y^4)$$
$$=2 (x^2 + x y + y^2)^2$$

Comment: Use LaTeX please: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?