# Factorization of polynomial $(a-b)^4+(b-c)^4+(c-a)^4$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Polynomial manifactoring of $(a-b)^4+(b-c)^4+(c-a)^4$
I've tried to factor all but didn't help.
I'm in sevent grade and don't know many techniques
So I wonder could someone help me.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Factoring to the multiplayers

Comment: I can factor it. I don't know what multiplayers are. Usually, one game, twenty-two players.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018565/factoring-a4b4a-b4/4018602?r=SearchResults#4018602

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factor $(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176542/factor-xy4x4y4); take $x=a-b$, $y=b-c$.

Comment: What is PSQ @lonestudent

Comment: @Aqua problem statement question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=a-b$ and $y=b-c$ then $a-c=x+y$ so we have \begin{align}...&= x^4+y^4+(x+y)^4\\
&= 2x^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4y^3x+2y^4\\
&= 2(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2y^3x+y^4)\\
&= 2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2
\end{align}

---

In general:

If $f(x,y)$ is 4 degree polynomial then you can try factor it by setting

$$f(x,y) = (ax^2+bxy+cy^2)(dx^2+exy+fy^2)$$  or $$f(x,y) = (ax+by)(cx^3+dx^2y+exy^2 +fy^3)$$ Now all you have to find are those coefficents.

Comment: Actually we need enough math practise , to observe, I think... $$x^4+2x^3y+\cdots+y^4=2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2$$ When you saw this, how did you know that it was a perfect square?  So mine is just curiosity...

Comment: Lucky guess, it looks like some square, I tried if this works and voila.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it

Answer (score 1):

One method is based on a simple observation and a simple guess.
Given the polynomial $\,P :=(a-b)^4+(b-c)^4+(c-a)^4\,$ to factor, notice
that if $\,a,b,c\,$ are all increased or decreased by the same
quantity, then the differences are unchanged. Thus, if $\,x=a-b,\;
y=b-c\,$ then
$$ P = x^4+y^4+(-x-y)^4 = 2(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4). $$
If $\,y=1\,$ and $\,x\,$ is a small integer, then the polynomial
factor is a square. For example, $\,x=y=1\,$ implies $\, P = 2\cdot3^2.\,$
A good guess is that it is a square of the form $\, P =2(ux^2+vxy+wy^2)^2\,$
for some integers $\,u,v,w\,$ and a good guess is that $\,u=v=w=1\,$
which is correct. Thus,
$$ P = 2(x^2+xy+y^2)^2 = 2((a-b)^2+(a-b)(b-c)+(b-c)^2)^2. $$

---

Another way is to find a systematic solution, but it requires some
advanced techniques that you almost certainly do not know yet. It
uses recursion relations and
[elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) which in this case are
$$ e_1 := x+y+z,\quad e_2 := xy+yz+zx,\quad e_3 :=xyz. \tag{1} $$
Define the power symmetric polynomials
$$ p_n := x^n + y^n + z^n. \tag{2} $$
The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials is that all such
polynomials can be expressed using the elementary symmetric polynomials.
The base case $\,p_0 = 3\,$ is immediate.
Next is, $\, p_1 = x+y+z = e_1.\,$ An easy calculation gets
$$ p_2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx) = e_1^2-2e_2. \tag{3} $$
Note that $$ e_2 = (ab+bc+ca)-(a^2+b^2+c^2). \tag{4} $$
In general, the power symmetric polynomials satisfy a recursion
$$ p_{n+3} = e_1 p_{n+2} - e_2 p_{n+1} + e_3 p_n. \tag{5} $$

In our particular case,
$$ x = a-b,\quad y = b-c,\quad z = c-a \tag{6} $$
which implies using equation $(3)$ that
$$ p_1 = e_1 = 0,\quad p_2 = -2e_2. \tag{7} $$
Use the recursion in equation $(5)$ to get
$$ p_3 = 3e_3,\quad p_4 = 2e_2^2. \tag{8} $$
Translate this in terms of $\,a,b,c\,$ to get
$$ p_3 = 3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a),\quad p_4 = 2e_2^2. \tag{9} $$

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*}
(a-b)^4+(b-c)^4+(c-a)^4 & = 2(a^2 - ab - ac + b^2 - bc + c^2)^2,
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176542/factor-xy4x4y4).

Comment: thank you now I see